# Use custom theme on ReadTheDocs

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I try to use a custom theme inherited from Sphinx's built-in ReadTheDocs Theme.

When I use it on my local computer I have the good design. But when I am on the read the doc version (imported from github) there is no CSS.

Did I miss something?

The repo with the branch using the custom theme: https://github.com/DigitalSkills-fr/Docs/tree/custom_theme/docs

The doc on RTD with the targeted branch: http://digitalskills-docs.readthedocs.io/fr/custom_theme/index.html

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify only built-in theme names in your [`conf.py`](https://github.com/DigitalSkills-fr/Docs/blob/custom_theme/docs/conf.py#L107).

```
# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.  See the documentation for
# a list of builtin themes.
#html_theme = 'default'
html_theme = 'theme_digitalskills'
```

Delete your custom entry and restore the original to:

```
html_theme = 'default'
```

Assuming you have modified the CSS files in your branch `custom_theme`, then RTD should copy all the files within the list of directories specified in `html_static_path`, overriding the built-in theme's CSS files:

```
# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_static_path = ['_static']
```