# Rendering discrepancy between ReadTheDocs and localhost

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I have just uploaded my documentation from Github to ReadTheDocs and I have found that it renders completely different on ReadTheDocs and my local machine. I am using the latest `sphinx_rtd_theme` on my local machine.

Here is the display on my local machine:

[image]

and here is the rendering on ReadTheDocs:

[image]

I have tried on Chrome, Firefox and Microsoft Edge with the same results so it does not appear to be a browser problem.

Here is a copy of my conf.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# This file does only contain a selection of the most common options. For a
# full list see the documentation:
# http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/config

# -- Path setup --------------------------------------------------------------

# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
#
# import sys
# sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))

import os


# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

project = 'OrderedTree'
project_title = 'Ordered Tree'
copyright = '2018, Jonathan Gossage'
author = 'Jonathan Gossage'

# The short X.Y version
version = '0.0'
# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags
release = '0.0.1'


# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

# If your documentation needs a minimal Sphinx version, state it here.
#
# needs_sphinx = '1.0'

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
    'sphinx.ext.todo',
    'sphinx.ext.mathjax',
    'sphinx.ext.ifconfig',
]

# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['_templates']

# The suffix(es) of source filenames.
# You can specify multiple suffix as a list of string:
#
# source_suffix = ['.rst', '.md']
source_suffix = '.rst'

# The master toctree document.
master_doc = 'index'

# The language for content autogenerated by Sphinx. Refer to documentation
# for a list of supported languages.
#
# This is also used if you do content translation via gettext catalogs.
# Usually you set "language" from the command line for these cases.
language = None

# List of patterns, relative to source directory, that match files and
# directories to ignore when looking for source files.
# This pattern also affects html_static_path and html_extra_path .
exclude_patterns = []

# The name of the Pygments (syntax highlighting) style to use.
pygments_style = 'sphinx'

# Elements to be included at yhe start of each document file
rst_prolog = """
.. |br| raw:: html

   <br />

.. |pn| replace:: {}
.. |pt| replace:: {}
""".format(project, project_title)


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.  See the documentation for
# a list of builtin themes.
#
#html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
on_rtd = os.environ.get('READTHEDOCS') == 'True'
if on_rtd:
    html_theme = 'default'
else:
    html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'

# Theme options are theme-specific and customize the look and feel of a theme
# further.  For a list of options available for each theme, see the
# documentation.
#
# html_theme_options = {}

# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
if on_rtd:
    html_static_path = []
else:
    html_static_path = ['_static']

html_context = {  # Specify the css file to use
    'css_files': ['_static/theme_overrides.css',]
    }

# Custom sidebar templates, must be a dictionary that maps document names
# to template names.
#
# The default sidebars (for documents that don't match any pattern) are
# defined by theme itself.  Builtin themes are using these templates by
# default: ``['localtoc.html', 'relations.html', 'sourcelink.html',
# 'searchbox.html']``.
#
# html_sidebars = {}


# -- Options for HTMLHelp output ---------------------------------------------

# Output file base name for HTML help builder.
htmlhelp_basename = '{}doc'.format(project)


# -- Options for LaTeX output ------------------------------------------------

latex_elements = {
    # The paper size ('letterpaper' or 'a4paper').
    #
    # 'papersize': 'letterpaper',

    # The font size ('10pt', '11pt' or '12pt').
    #
    # 'pointsize': '10pt',

    # Additional stuff for the LaTeX preamble.
    #
    # 'preamble': '',

    # Latex figure (float) alignment
    #
    # 'figure_align': 'htbp',
}

# Grouping the document tree into LaTeX files. List of tuples
# (source start file, target name, title,
#  author, documentclass [howto, manual, or own class]).
latex_documents = [
    (master_doc, '{}.tex'.format(project), '{} Documentation'.format(project_title),
     '{}'.format(author), 'manual'),
]


# -- Options for manual page output ------------------------------------------

# One entry per manual page. List of tuples
# (source start file, name, description, authors, manual section).
man_pages = [
    (master_doc, '{}'.format(project), '{} Documentation'.format(project_title),
     [author], 1)
]


# -- Options for Texinfo output ----------------------------------------------

# Grouping the document tree into Texinfo files. List of tuples
# (source start file, target name, title, author,
#  dir menu entry, description, category)
texinfo_documents = [
    (master_doc, '{}'.format(project), '{} Documentation'.format(project_title),
     author, '{}'.format(project), 'One line description of project.',
     'Miscellaneous'),
]


# -- Options for Epub output -------------------------------------------------

# Bibliographic Dublin Core info.
epub_title = project_title
epub_author = author
epub_publisher = author
epub_copyright = copyright

# The unique identifier of the text. This can be a ISBN number
# or the project homepage.
#
# epub_identifier = ''

# A unique identification for the text.
#
# epub_uid = ''

# A list of files that should not be packed into the epub file.
epub_exclude_files = ['search.html']


# -- Extension configuration -------------------------------------------------

# -- Options for intersphinx extension ---------------------------------------

# Example configuration for intersphinx: refer to the Python standard library.
intersphinx_mapping = {'https://docs.python.org/': None}

# -- Options for todo extension ----------------------------------------------

# If true, `todo` and `todoList` produce output, else they produce nothing.
todo_include_todos = True
```

I have determined what is causing the problem but I have no idea why it is happening or how to fix it. I am using a boiler-plate fragment of HTML from Creative Commons which identifies the license governing use of the documentation. I took the base `sphinx_rtd_theme Footer.html` and added this fragment to it and used the modified `Footer.html` to override the base copy. The fragment follows:

```
    <br /> <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/">
    <img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-sa/4.0/88x31.png" /></a>
    <br />
  <p>
    This work is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/">Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International License</a>
  </p>
```

The fragment actually works as this HTML is correctly rendered on ReadTheDocs but the rest of the formatting disappears.

What do I need to do to get the local display on ReadTheDocs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45878953/use-custom-theme-on-readthedocs See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/44175925/2214933

Comment: @Steve Unfortunately using the default theme gives the same results. I know it is using the sphinx_rtd_theme as I have overridden the block extrafooter in the footer and that is working correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like static assets are not getting copied over on RTD. Let's look at the [build log](https://readthedocs.org/projects/orderedtree/builds/7113767/), under `python /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/orderedtree/envs/latest/bin/sphinx-build -T -E -b readthedocs -d _build/doctrees-readthedocs -D language=en . _build/html`:

```
copying static files... WARNING: html_static_path entry '/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/readthedocs/templates/sphinx/_static' does not exist
```

You know what?  [That error sounds strangely familiar for some reason...](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/1776).

Let's see the setting in your [`conf.py`](https://github.com/jfgossage/OrderedTree/blob/master/docs/source/conf.py#L110):

```
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

Try changing that to:

```
html_static_path = []
```

Seems to work for about a dozen other users.

Comment: This does not work unfortunately. The rendered result is the same. I have added the` conf.py` file  to the post.

Comment: Suggest isolating possibilities. Start with an unmodified `conf.py` (the one created by Sphinx quick-start) and turn off Admin settings in RTD that build from a requirements file.

Comment: How can I determine if the file _templates\footer.html``was updated on ReadTheDocs when it was the only file changed? It is updated OK on GitHub. The behavior I am seeing suggests that I am using an older version.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the solution to your problem includes setting `html_static_path = []` and potentially in one more thing. First get RTD to build your docs with its native RTD theme. Then start making one and only one tweak at a time to isolate the cause of breakage. It is possible that RTD will install the native RTD theme and ignore any customizations you attempt. As a last resort, you could create a separate theme package based on RTD's theme, then install that in your requirements file and specify same in your `conf.py`.

Comment: I have found the problem. I was using a little CSS to center the text in the footer. To do this I set the conf file variable html_context to the name of my CSS file. The problem was that doing this overrides the theme's basic CSS rather than adding to it. To fix this it looks as if I need to add the CSS files from the base theme to this variable. If I copy these files into my environment I will have a maintenance problem as I will need to refresh them every time sphinx_rtd_theme releases a new version.

Comment: To expand on this, I am using Sphinx 1.7.4 locally whereas ReadTheDocs uses 1.6.5. The behavior of the html<-context variable is different in the two versions which is why my original setup worked on my local machine but not on ReadTheDocs.

Comment: You can [specify the version of Sphinx on RTD](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/4015#issuecomment-384114514). Are you following my original comments for modifying a theme? If you go off-road, you're on your own.

Comment: Can confirm that deleting '_static' from conf.py worked for me as suggested above